# Can I mute audio for a WebGl container?

Tags: javascript, html, unity-game-engine, webgl

I want to add an html "audio off" button to a webpage containing a WebGL Unity game.

I know I can do adding a button to my webgl game, but I want to do with outside html button.

My code:

```
<img id="btnaudio" src="images/audio-on.png" style="height: 24px;" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Audio On/Off" onclick="switchAudio();" />

        <div id="gameContainer" ></div>


        function switchAudio() {
            document.getElementById("gameContainer").muted = !document.getElementById("gameContainer").muted;
            var img = document.getElementById('btnaudio');
            if(document.getElementById("gameContainer").muted)
                img.src='images/audio-on.png';
            else
                img.src='images/audio-off.png';
        }
```

But it not work.. audio keep playing (but image swap so, js code is executed).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think one way would probably be to simply turn off the camera's `AudioListener` component.

You can [call methods in your Unity scene from the page's JavaScript](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html) e.g. like

c# code

```
public class MuteController : MonoBehaviour
{
    // For storing previous volumes
    private readonly Dictionary<AudioListener, float> mutedListeners = new Dictionary<AudioListener, float>();

    public void Mute()
    {
        foreach (var listener in FindObjectsOfType<AudioListener>())
        {
            mutedListeners.Add(listener, listener.volume);
            listener.volume = 0;
        }
    }

    public void Unmute()
    {
        foreach (var kvp in mutedListeners)
        {
            kvp.Key.volume = kvp.Value;
        }

        mutedListeners.Clear();
    }
}
```

Put it on a `GameObject` in your scene with the name `MuteController`.

And then call these methods from the JavaScript code like e.g.

```
unityInstance.SendMessage('MuteController', 'Mute');
```

and

```
unityInstance.SendMessage('MuteController', 'Unmute');
```